# node extraction doesn't work for double linked list

Tags: c

I am trying to extract the first node from a double linked list and then display the changes, but after I call the function extractNode, it retrieves the right node, but the list's attributes get some random values. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

```
struct Train { 
    int code;
    char* name;
};

struct node {
    Train info;
    node* next;
    node* prev;

};

struct DoubleLinkedList {
    node* first;
    node* last;

};

Train createTrain(int cod, const char* name) {
    Train t;
    t.code = cod;
    t.name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(1 + strlen(name)));
    strcpy(t.name, name);
    return t;
}
node* createNode(Train t, node* next, node* prev) {
    node* nou = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    nou->info = t;
    nou->next = next;
    nou->prev = prev;

    return nou;
}
DoubleLinkedList insertAtTheBeginning(DoubleLinkedList list,Train a) {
    node* newNode = createNode(a, list.first, NULL);
    if (list.first) {
        newNode->next = list.first;
        list.first->prev = newNode;
        list.first = newNode;
    }
    else {
        list.first = newNode;
        list.last = newNode;
    }

    return list;

}



void displayTrain(Train t) {
    printf("\n name: %s , code:%d \n", t.name, t.code);


}

void crossDoubleLinkedList(DoubleLinkedList list) {
    node* temp = list.first;
    while (temp) {

        displayTrain(temp->info);
        temp = temp->next;
    }

}

node* extractNode(DoubleLinkedList list, int cod) {
    node* extractedNode = NULL;
    if (list.first == NULL) { return extractedNode; }
    if (list.first->info.code == cod) {
        node* extractedNode = createNode(createTrain(list.first->info.code, list.first->info.name), list.first->next, NULL);
        list.first->next->prev = NULL;
            node* copy = list.first;
        list.first = list.first->next;
        free(copy->info.name);
        free(copy);
        copy = NULL;

        return extractedNode;
    }

}

void main() {
    DoubleLinkedList list;
    list.first = NULL;
    list.last = NULL;
        list = insertAtTheBeginning(list, createTrain(1, "train1"));
    list = insertAtTheBeginning(list, createTrain(2, "train2"));
    crossDoubleLinkedList(list);
    node* d = extractNode(list, 2);
    crossDoubleLinkedList(list);
    system("pause");

};
```

I expected the list to have only train1, but instead it has
: info  {code=-572662307 name=0xdddddddd  }Train

Comment: What does your `extractNode` function return if `list.first->info.code != cod`?

Comment: And what is `extractNode` supposed to do? To remove a node from the list? *Any* node or a specific node?

Comment: Oh, and don't forget that arguments in C are passed *by value*. That means your structure `list` is *copied*, and when you do e.g. `list.first = list.first->next` you only modify the *local copy*.

Comment: extractNode returns the node that is being deleted, but I expect the function to also modify my list by removing the node. I should have removed if (list.first->info.code == cod) and the cod passed parameter, I only want to remove the first node of the list.

Comment: Did you understand "Some programmer dude's" message? You need to pass your list into the remove method like this; node* extractNode(DoubleLinkedList* list, int cod) or changes won't be permanent. Other code has to be changed to match the new method. Otherwise your code works.

Comment: It worked like a charm with the added "*" for the extractNode function, and the further changes needed. Thank you very much!